# Catch stored procedure output into a variable without using out params

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-variables

Consider the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getFoo`()
BEGIN
    select 'bar' as foo;
END;
```

Once `call`-ed, it outputs:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

But what if `getFoo` is invoked within a **different** stored procedure, how do I catch its result content into a variable, like this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `masterProc`()
BEGIN
    call `getFoo`() into @foo;
    select @foo as foo;
END;
```

This outputs the following error when invoked:  `sqlMessage: "FUNCTION db.getFoo does not exist"`

I am aware of the available options involving `out` parameters, but those are *not* viable resolution(s) to my problem.

**Obligation(s)**

`getFoo` cannot be altered. It will output the results of a `SELECT` statement without involving any `variables` nor `parameters`.

**What I've tried**

Unfortunately, all will output errors.

`set @foo = exec getFoo();`
`set @foo = call getFoo();`
`select getFoo() into @foo;`
`call getFoo() into @foo;`

Comment: I haven't come across currentFunction: in mysql before - do you have a reference for it?

Comment: @P.Salmon Snap I forgot to remove it. It is used for `GOTO` and `leave` purposes. Edited the question and removed *statement labels*.

Comment: There is no goto in mysql either..

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/statement-labels.html

Comment: Yeah there is no `GOTO` statement by itself, but there are workarounds to achieve similar-to-goto workflows.

Comment: @P.Salmon That throws `ER_PARSE_ERROR`. See **What I've tried**

Comment: SP's output is sent to output stream and cannot be re-captured from there by SQL code. Either OUT parameters or external storage (user-defined variable, temporary table, etc.) may help.

Comment: @Akina What if `EXEC` of a prepared statement is involved?

Comment: This changes nothing.

Comment: @Akina so MySQL has no solution for this?

Comment: You should maybe tell us what you are trying to achieve, rather than trying to 'fix' a non workable solution.

Comment: Yes, noway. SP output cannot be used as row source for a query in MySQL.

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for the effort but I think what I want to achieve is pretty clear within my question. Evidently, there is no working/workable solution attached but just trials, and including them is how a proper SO question should be structured.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch the result set (from `SELECT`) from another procedure. You have couple of options to do similar thing:

1. Put the result set in temporary table. Works for multiple rows.
2. Use OUT-variable (best for single values)
3. Use user-defined variable (@var) (be careful with these as calls to other procedure can change the values)

Create the getFoo():

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getFoo()
BEGIN
drop temporary table if exists temptable;

create temporary table temptable 
as 
select col1, col2 FROM table1;

END;
```

Create the masterProc():

```
CREATE PROCEDURE masterProc()
BEGIN
    call getFoo();

    select *
    from temptable;
END $$
```

Call masterProc():

```
call masterProc();
```

Comment: Can you attach a working example whereas `getFoo` outputs a table-like result and not a single column-value? Highly appreciated, thank you

Comment: @Constantin Example with temporary table added

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can invoke an SP in mysql is with a CALL the error you get is because you are attempting to invoke a function which does not exist. User defined variables (at variables) are available anywhere

```
drop procedure if exists getfoo;
drop procedure if exists masterproc;
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getFoo`()
BEGIN
    set @foo = 'foo';
END $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `masterProc`()
BEGIN
    call `getFoo`();
    select @foo as foo;
END $$

delimiter ;

call masterproc();

+------+
| foo  |
+------+
| foo  |
+------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Your solution does not catch a *stored procedure*'s `SELECT` output into a variable of a master procedure. Your master procedure selects a variable persisting in the nested procedure, instead.

Comment: @Constantin *catch a stored procedure's SELECT output into a variable of a master procedure* Impossible.